# Create outline on semi-transparent text

Tags: android, textview, shadow

I have text that is on top of another view.  To make the text readable I want to put an outline on the text.  IE. white text (with transparency) with an black opaque outline.

I am messing with this style:

```
<style name="MyText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#AFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
</style>
```

The problem here is that the shadow sits behind the text and if the shadow is opaque and the text is transparent the black shawdow shows through the white transparent text.  Defeats the purpose of the transparent text as I cannot see the view beneath, only the opaque shadow.

Can you create the shadow/outline only on the outside of the text?

**EDIT:** Screenshot for the non believers ;)

Please note that I changed the colors for the screenshot to make it very obvious.

```
<style name="MyText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#77FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
</style>
```

Notice the text color is transparent white, and the shadow color is red.  What I really want is a red outline on the transparent white text.  However since the text is transparent the red shadow beneath is showing through.  Is there a way to get the outline/shadow only on the outside of the text?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: See edit, attached screenshot.